# Translation of Swift to Objective-C possible?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

We started a new OS X project based on Swift, only to find out that the management doesn't really like that just through the use of Swift, we cannot sell the application to users before 10.9, even if 30% of the market still has older OS X versions.

Reimplementing the software in Objective-C seems to be the only solution. As Apple advertised Swift to be binary-compatible with Obj-C, **I'm wondering if a translation of Swift source code to Obj-C source code is theoretically possible, and if so, if you know about any implementation of that idea**.

Couldn't find anything about this topic on the web so far, everyone seems to be searching for the other direction at the moment.

Comment: How much code are we talking about?

Comment: A desktop application, not too much complexity, but also a lot of UI code. A code translator would save us at least 1 man month of work. The nice thing about Swift is the language itself, but we recognized too late that even when Yosemite is out and the adoption is as fast as with Mavericks last year, we'd be missing out 30% of all OS X installation just due to the language, not because of any APIs we need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible. But I am afraid there's no tools to do that. You should rewrite all the codes manually.

As you mentioned, Swift and Objective-C codes can work together perfectly. So I think rewrite the codes one class/file by one should be a good way.

Apple's document `Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C` https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/ should be help.